# how to configure git hook post-recieve to update a mirror repository after being pushed?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, git-post-receive

i have a bare repository in the Gitlab server, and the same repository has been mirrored into another server using ssh. i would like to assign a post-receive hook into Gitlab repository in order to update the mirrored repository after the user has been pushed to the Gitlab repository.

according to Gitlab documentation, i can make git hooks like below
[image]

but what should i put in the URL?? the mirrored repository server path ?
or is there anyway i can make this to achieve using git hooks ?

my Gitlab version is Community Edition 11.1.4

Answer (score 0):

> what should i put in the URL?? the mirrored repository server path ?

No: you should use the URL of a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) listener that *you* put in place beforehand.
You can inspect a webhook answer with a [self-hosted requestBin instance](https://github.com/Runscope/requestbin#readme).

Examples:

- [ahebrank/gitlab-webhook-handler](https://github.com/ahebrank/gitlab-webhook-handler)
- [Custom webhook](https://hackernoon.com/71-seconds-to-build-your-free-custom-webhook-illustrated-step-by-step-7a09b9e240ba)
- [Setting GitLab webhook](https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Continuum/Getting_Started/Receiving_Change_(commits)_in_Continuum/Setup_GitLab_Webhook)

> is there anyway i can make this to achieve using git hooks ?

Only if you have access to the GitLab server. That would not be possible for instance for gitlab.com.